# Google Sheets: Is there a way to have 2 un-nested IF statements in the formula?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

I'm trying to have these 2 statements work in a single cell in Google Sheets/Spreadsheets without having to use additional cells?:

```
IF(A1="x", "YES")
IF(B1="x", "SIR")
```

For example, if A1 has 'x' and B1 has 'x', I'd like to see "YESSIR" in C1. If either has 'x', then C1 either should have "YES" or "SIR" respectively.

I believe this can easily be achieved by creating 2 additional columns that would allow me to concatenate. However, I want to limit the use to only one column for the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` with `IF` inside single column, i.e. formula will be:

```
=CONCAT(IF(A1="x","YES",""),IF(B1="x","SIR",""))

A1  B1  RESULT
x   x   YESSIR
f   f   
x   f   YES
f   x   SIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom function. Here's what you enter: =specialOr(A1,"x","yes",A2,"x","sir")

```
function specialOr(val1,match1,output1,val2,match2,output2)
{
  if(val1==match1 && val2==match2)
  {
    return String(output1 + output2);
  }else 
  if(val1==match1 && val2!=match2)
  {
    return output1;
  }else
  if(val2==match2 && val1!=match2)
  {
    return output2
  }else
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPT` along with concatenation operator `&` :

```
=REPT("YES", A1="x") & REPT("SIR",B1="x")
```